Modification in Wordpress htaccess file
I encountered a big while trying to add my subscrition managment to my Wordpress site. In instructions they said to add these lines in htaccess:
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ p.php?id=$1&chk=$2
RewriteRule ^r/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ r.php?id=$1&chk=$2&tcode=$3
RewriteRule ^r/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ r.php?id=$1&chk=$2
RewriteRule ^abuse/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ abuse.php?id=$1&chk=$2
RewriteRule ^abuse/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ abuse.php?id=$1&chk=$2&tcode=$3
RewriteRule ^link/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ link.php?data1=$1&data2=$2&data3=$3&data4=$4

But when I add them to WP htaccess it does not work. When I replace defualt htaccess with the code above subscrption works byt any Wordpress subpage gives 404 error.
Is there any way to somehow merge these lines together?

In instructions they said... who is "they" ? it's strange to ask to edit htaccess file because plugins can define new rewrite rules themselves. moreover using direct access to a php file don't look like correct either. what are you installing ?

@mmm It is some old newsletter subscription system. It is not a plugin for WP, I'm just trying to make it work with Wordpress installed in the same folder.

That won't work. Wordpress relies on all requests being rewritten to it's controller, as all CMS systems do. You cannot simply place a "page" in there and expect everything to just work.

Old like working with php < 7 when your WordPress probably works with 8+ ? Is it rly good idea to use "old" system ? Whats wrong with the plugins for WordPress ?
